# JSONPath to exclude item in array with value containing matching string

Tags: kubectl, jsonpath

I am using `kubectl` and trying to run `kubectl get nodes` and exclude any master nodes from the results.
My end goal is to get a list of the IP addresses of the worker nodes.

This command gives me all of the nodes IP addresses (including master nodes):

```
kubectl get nodes -o jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{.status.addresses[?(@.type=='InternalIP')].address}{'\n'}{end}"
```

But as I said, I need to exclude any master nodes.  The path to the name is: `.metadata.name`.  I need to exclude from the `range` any `.metadata.name`s that contain the text `-master-`.  (UPDATE: Alternativly, I could only include ones that contain the text `-worker-`.)

I an find equal, and not equal.  But I can't seem to find a way to do a "contains" or "regex" ability.

**How can exclude items that match a pattern?**

Comment: faced similar issue, related read here https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/20352

Comment: apparently, kubectl's `jsonpath` implementation is not powerful as the native jsonpath.  in regards to  usage of `&&` while solving the above question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such usecase you can use label selector.

Since all master nodes have `node-role.kubernetes.io/master: ""` label. you can use it to exclude these nodes. Use:

```
kubectl get no -l node-role.kubernetes.io/master!=""
```

If your worker nodes have some specific label you can use it as an atlernative selector.

---

The thing you are trying to do: match patterns; is not possible with built in jsonpath since its limited functionality, but you can use `jq` for this usecase if you really don't like lables and selectors.